# issues with displaying iteams in dart

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, google-api

```
 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      Future getData() async {
        var url =
            "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=book";
    
        var response = await http.get(url);
        var responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print(responseBody);
    
        return responseBody;
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        getData();
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: FutureBuilder(
              future: getData(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
    
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 25,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                            child: Text(snapshot.data[index]['items']));
                      });
                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              }),
        );
      }
    }
```

im trying to a display the fetched data from google api's, thier seems to be a issue with displaying the book volumes.

it refused to show book volumes in a `ListView`.

am i doing somthing wong ? or is thier a better way to do it ?

you can also use https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ to convert it.

Comment: What exact error are you getting?

Comment: im just trying get the book volumes, then showing them in a `ListView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was your item builder. you used a fixed list count of 25 and there were less items in the data. Also putting an entire json object in a `Text` widget won't work. I used json to dart to convert the json output to a model for you and fixed the listviewbuilder + Future for you. This should get you going!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<BookResponse> getData() async {
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=book";

    var response = await http.get(url);
    var responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(responseBody);

    return BookResponse.fromJson(responseBody);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<BookResponse>(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                        child: Text(
                      snapshot.data.items[index].kind,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ));
                  });
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}

class BookResponse {
  String kind;
  int totalItems;
  List<Items> items;

  BookResponse({this.kind, this.totalItems, this.items});

  BookResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    kind = json['kind'];
    totalItems = json['totalItems'];
    if (json['items'] != null) {
      items = new List<Items>();
      json['items'].forEach((v) {
        items.add(new Items.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['kind'] = this.kind;
    data['totalItems'] = this.totalItems;
    if (this.items != null) {
      data['items'] = this.items.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Items {
  String kind;
  String id;
  String etag;
  String selfLink;
  VolumeInfo volumeInfo;
  SaleInfo saleInfo;
  AccessInfo accessInfo;
  SearchInfo searchInfo;

  Items(
      {this.kind,
      this.id,
      this.etag,
      this.selfLink,
      this.volumeInfo,
      this.saleInfo,
      this.accessInfo,
      this.searchInfo});

  Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    kind = json['kind'];
    id = json['id'];
    etag = json['etag'];
    selfLink = json['selfLink'];
    volumeInfo = json['volumeInfo'] != null
        ? new VolumeInfo.fromJson(json['volumeInfo'])
        : null;
    saleInfo = json['saleInfo'] != null
        ? new SaleInfo.fromJson(json['saleInfo'])
        : null;
    accessInfo = json['accessInfo'] != null
        ? new AccessInfo.fromJson(json['accessInfo'])
        : null;
    searchInfo = json['searchInfo'] != null
        ? new SearchInfo.fromJson(json['searchInfo'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['kind'] = this.kind;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['etag'] = this.etag;
    data['selfLink'] = this.selfLink;
    if (this.volumeInfo != null) {
      data['volumeInfo'] = this.volumeInfo.toJson();
    }
    if (this.saleInfo != null) {
      data['saleInfo'] = this.saleInfo.toJson();
    }
    if (this.accessInfo != null) {
      data['accessInfo'] = this.accessInfo.toJson();
    }
    if (this.searchInfo != null) {
      data['searchInfo'] = this.searchInfo.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class VolumeInfo {
  String title;
  String subtitle;
  List<String> authors;
  String publisher;
  String publishedDate;
  String description;
  List<IndustryIdentifiers> industryIdentifiers;
  ReadingModes readingModes;
  int pageCount;
  String printType;
  List<String> categories;
  double averageRating;
  int ratingsCount;
  String maturityRating;
  bool allowAnonLogging;
  String contentVersion;
  PanelizationSummary panelizationSummary;
  ImageLinks imageLinks;
  String language;
  String previewLink;
  String infoLink;
  String canonicalVolumeLink;

  VolumeInfo(
      {this.title,
      this.subtitle,
      this.authors,
      this.publisher,
      this.publishedDate,
      this.description,
      this.industryIdentifiers,
      this.readingModes,
      this.pageCount,
      this.printType,
      this.categories,
      this.averageRating,
      this.ratingsCount,
      this.maturityRating,
      this.allowAnonLogging,
      this.contentVersion,
      this.panelizationSummary,
      this.imageLinks,
      this.language,
      this.previewLink,
      this.infoLink,
      this.canonicalVolumeLink});

  VolumeInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json['title'];
    subtitle = json['subtitle'];
    authors = json['authors']?.cast<String>();
    publisher = json['publisher'];
    publishedDate = json['publishedDate'];
    description = json['description'];
    if (json['industryIdentifiers'] != null) {
      industryIdentifiers = new List<IndustryIdentifiers>();
      json['industryIdentifiers'].forEach((v) {
        industryIdentifiers.add(new IndustryIdentifiers.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    readingModes = json['readingModes'] != null
        ? new ReadingModes.fromJson(json['readingModes'])
        : null;
    pageCount = json['pageCount'];
    printType = json['printType'];
    categories = json['categories']?.cast<String>();
    averageRating = double.parse(json['averageRating']?.toString() ?? '0');
    ratingsCount = json['ratingsCount'];
    maturityRating = json['maturityRating'];
    allowAnonLogging = json['allowAnonLogging'];
    contentVersion = json['contentVersion'];
    panelizationSummary = json['panelizationSummary'] != null
        ? new PanelizationSummary.fromJson(json['panelizationSummary'])
        : null;
    imageLinks = json['imageLinks'] != null
        ? new ImageLinks.fromJson(json['imageLinks'])
        : null;
    language = json['language'];
    previewLink = json['previewLink'];
    infoLink = json['infoLink'];
    canonicalVolumeLink = json['canonicalVolumeLink'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['subtitle'] = this.subtitle;
    data['authors'] = this.authors;
    data['publisher'] = this.publisher;
    data['publishedDate'] = this.publishedDate;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    if (this.industryIdentifiers != null) {
      data['industryIdentifiers'] =
          this.industryIdentifiers.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.readingModes != null) {
      data['readingModes'] = this.readingModes.toJson();
    }
    data['pageCount'] = this.pageCount;
    data['printType'] = this.printType;
    data['categories'] = this.categories;
    data['averageRating'] = this.averageRating;
    data['ratingsCount'] = this.ratingsCount;
    data['maturityRating'] = this.maturityRating;
    data['allowAnonLogging'] = this.allowAnonLogging;
    data['contentVersion'] = this.contentVersion;
    if (this.panelizationSummary != null) {
      data['panelizationSummary'] = this.panelizationSummary.toJson();
    }
    if (this.imageLinks != null) {
      data['imageLinks'] = this.imageLinks.toJson();
    }
    data['language'] = this.language;
    data['previewLink'] = this.previewLink;
    data['infoLink'] = this.infoLink;
    data['canonicalVolumeLink'] = this.canonicalVolumeLink;
    return data;
  }
}

class IndustryIdentifiers {
  String type;
  String identifier;

  IndustryIdentifiers({this.type, this.identifier});

  IndustryIdentifiers.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    type = json['type'];
    identifier = json['identifier'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['identifier'] = this.identifier;
    return data;
  }
}

class ReadingModes {
  bool text;
  bool image;

  ReadingModes({this.text, this.image});

  ReadingModes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    text = json['text'];
    image = json['image'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['text'] = this.text;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    return data;
  }
}

class PanelizationSummary {
  bool containsEpubBubbles;
  bool containsImageBubbles;

  PanelizationSummary({this.containsEpubBubbles, this.containsImageBubbles});

  PanelizationSummary.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    containsEpubBubbles = json['containsEpubBubbles'];
    containsImageBubbles = json['containsImageBubbles'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['containsEpubBubbles'] = this.containsEpubBubbles;
    data['containsImageBubbles'] = this.containsImageBubbles;
    return data;
  }
}

class ImageLinks {
  String smallThumbnail;
  String thumbnail;

  ImageLinks({this.smallThumbnail, this.thumbnail});

  ImageLinks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    smallThumbnail = json['smallThumbnail'];
    thumbnail = json['thumbnail'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['smallThumbnail'] = this.smallThumbnail;
    data['thumbnail'] = this.thumbnail;
    return data;
  }
}

class SaleInfo {
  String country;
  String saleability;
  bool isEbook;
  ListPrice listPrice;
  ListPrice retailPrice;
  String buyLink;
  List<Offers> offers;

  SaleInfo(
      {this.country,
      this.saleability,
      this.isEbook,
      this.listPrice,
      this.retailPrice,
      this.buyLink,
      this.offers});

  SaleInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    country = json['country'];
    saleability = json['saleability'];
    isEbook = json['isEbook'];
    listPrice = json['listPrice'] != null
        ? new ListPrice.fromJson(json['listPrice'])
        : null;
    retailPrice = json['retailPrice'] != null
        ? new ListPrice.fromJson(json['retailPrice'])
        : null;
    buyLink = json['buyLink'];
    if (json['offers'] != null) {
      offers = new List<Offers>();
      json['offers'].forEach((v) {
        offers.add(new Offers.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['country'] = this.country;
    data['saleability'] = this.saleability;
    data['isEbook'] = this.isEbook;
    if (this.listPrice != null) {
      data['listPrice'] = this.listPrice.toJson();
    }
    if (this.retailPrice != null) {
      data['retailPrice'] = this.retailPrice.toJson();
    }
    data['buyLink'] = this.buyLink;
    if (this.offers != null) {
      data['offers'] = this.offers.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class ListPrice {
  double amount;
  String currencyCode;

  ListPrice({this.amount, this.currencyCode});

  ListPrice.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    amount = json['amount'];
    currencyCode = json['currencyCode'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['amount'] = this.amount;
    data['currencyCode'] = this.currencyCode;
    return data;
  }
}

class Offers {
  int finskyOfferType;
  ListPrice listPrice;
  ListPrice retailPrice;

  Offers({this.finskyOfferType, this.listPrice, this.retailPrice});

  Offers.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    finskyOfferType = json['finskyOfferType'];
    listPrice = json['listPrice'] != null
        ? new ListPrice.fromJson(json['listPrice'])
        : null;
    retailPrice = json['retailPrice'] != null
        ? new ListPrice.fromJson(json['retailPrice'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['finskyOfferType'] = this.finskyOfferType;
    if (this.listPrice != null) {
      data['listPrice'] = this.listPrice.toJson();
    }
    if (this.retailPrice != null) {
      data['retailPrice'] = this.retailPrice.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class AccessInfo {
  String country;
  String viewability;
  bool embeddable;
  bool publicDomain;
  String textToSpeechPermission;
  Epub epub;
  Epub pdf;
  String webReaderLink;
  String accessViewStatus;
  bool quoteSharingAllowed;

  AccessInfo(
      {this.country,
      this.viewability,
      this.embeddable,
      this.publicDomain,
      this.textToSpeechPermission,
      this.epub,
      this.pdf,
      this.webReaderLink,
      this.accessViewStatus,
      this.quoteSharingAllowed});

  AccessInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    country = json['country'];
    viewability = json['viewability'];
    embeddable = json['embeddable'];
    publicDomain = json['publicDomain'];
    textToSpeechPermission = json['textToSpeechPermission'];
    epub = json['epub'] != null ? new Epub.fromJson(json['epub']) : null;
    pdf = json['pdf'] != null ? new Epub.fromJson(json['pdf']) : null;
    webReaderLink = json['webReaderLink'];
    accessViewStatus = json['accessViewStatus'];
    quoteSharingAllowed = json['quoteSharingAllowed'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['country'] = this.country;
    data['viewability'] = this.viewability;
    data['embeddable'] = this.embeddable;
    data['publicDomain'] = this.publicDomain;
    data['textToSpeechPermission'] = this.textToSpeechPermission;
    if (this.epub != null) {
      data['epub'] = this.epub.toJson();
    }
    if (this.pdf != null) {
      data['pdf'] = this.pdf.toJson();
    }
    data['webReaderLink'] = this.webReaderLink;
    data['accessViewStatus'] = this.accessViewStatus;
    data['quoteSharingAllowed'] = this.quoteSharingAllowed;
    return data;
  }
}

class Epub {
  bool isAvailable;
  String acsTokenLink;
  String downloadLink;

  Epub({this.isAvailable, this.acsTokenLink, this.downloadLink});

  Epub.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    isAvailable = json['isAvailable'];
    acsTokenLink = json['acsTokenLink'];
    downloadLink = json['downloadLink'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['isAvailable'] = this.isAvailable;
    data['acsTokenLink'] = this.acsTokenLink;
    data['downloadLink'] = this.downloadLink;
    return data;
  }
}

class SearchInfo {
  String textSnippet;

  SearchInfo({this.textSnippet});

  SearchInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    textSnippet = json['textSnippet'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['textSnippet'] = this.textSnippet;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so you much, i worked perfectly fine.

the response shows a total of 641 books, 

but in the divice it's shows 10 at a time, is this normal ? is it possible to extended it ? i want it to display all  641